# Runtime mapping of values to types

Tags: c++

I have no hope that what I'd like to achieve is possible in C++, but maybe I'm wrong since my previous question about [bidirectional static mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448834/concise-bidirectional-static-11-mapping-of-values-and-types) got an unlikely answer.

I have a set of certain types, an enumeration with keys representing the types, and a template handle type that accepts mentioned types as template parameters.

```cpp
struct foo {};
struct bar {};

enum class types { foo, bar };

template<typename T>
struct qux {};
```

I'd like to be able to map `types::foo` to `foo` at runtime. Most of the time `foo` would be used as the template parameter of `qux`, so mapping of `types::foo` to `qux<foo>` is fine too but I feel that if one is possible, then the other is too.

I'm mentioning this because it's important to note that `qux` is a simple handle-like type that only consists of an index and is passed around by value and there are a lot of template functions that take `qux<T>` as a parameter.

This makes polymorphism - a standard solution in such cases - not an obvious choice.

Sometimes though I need to create a `qux<T>` while having only a variable holding a `types` value, so it has to be mapped to the proper type somehow.

What I've been doing up until now is just `switch`ing each time I have to do this but I hit the point where there's too many `switch`es to maintain.

I don't see a better solution, so what I'm looking to do is create a single `swich` or other mechanism in the code that will take `types` value and return... something that will let me create a `qux<T>` with related type.

Ultimately it'd work like this.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void baz(qux<T> q) { /* ... */ }

// Somewhere else...
types t = get_type(); // Read type at runtime.
baz(create_object(t)); // Calls adequate baz specialization based on what value t contains.
```

I don't know how to implement the `create_object` function though.

---

What I tried already:

1. `std::variant` with careful use of `emplace` and `index` - quickly hit the problem of being unable to return different types from a single function;
2. [clever use of conversion operators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191106-00/?p=103066) - doesn't allow me to call a proper templated function taking `qux<T>` as a parameter since it's not decided which specialization should be called;
3. [external polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653596/7236144) - unable to return different types;
4. modified template specialization loop proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38590464/7236144) that looked for proper `types` value and returned mapped type - this failed due to being unable to return different types - or called a lambda with `auto` parameter - which also failed as it tried to specialize the lambda multiple times.

Comment: Templates are instantiated at compile-time. `qux::<foo>` needs to be instantiated at compile-time, which won't happen if the mapping happens at run-time.

Comment: The best you can really do here if you go down that route is to perform some kind of type erasure such that you have a type-erased class (like `void*`) that gets returned from some `create` function that receives some input, like a hash_code from a `type_info` struct and has the correct mapping to a function that returns a `qux<foo>` type-erased as `void*`, and then the caller has to perform a `static_cast` to recover the type.

Comment: But it sounds like you want an auto-registering factory pattern where the types *are* known at compile-time.

Comment: `std::variant` seems like exactly the right tool here. What did you try? In your example, `create_object` should return `std::variant<qux<foo>, qux<bar>>` and you'd call `baz` with `std::visit([&](auto &&x) -> decltype(auto) { return baz(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)); }, create_object(t))` (yes, the incantation is long, but there's a lot going on to make this work). Heck, `std::variant` works so well it can straight-up replace `types`: `using types = std::variant<std::type_identity<foo>, std::type_identity<bar>>`, which might help clean things up (or might not, idk).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too many if/else statements in converting user inputs to types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61309900/too-many-if-else-statements-in-converting-user-inputs-to-types-in-c)

Comment: @HTNW I believe it does but judging by how convoluted the solution is I'd rather use `std::variant` with `std::visit` as you suggested. I tested your approach and although it requires lambda expressions for each usage it works fine and is even more powerful than I expected it to be. For now I implemented an imitation of `std::visit` inside the type I use to pass around the generalised handle. If you make an answer out of your comment regarding `std::variant` I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Vennor I've gone and simplified my answer there. I have no idea why I made it so complicated. If you've implemented `std::visit` inside `types` then you've basically made `types` into `std::variant` anyway (`std::variant` basically *is* `std::visit`). My suggestion to have `create_object` return a `std::variant` is but a variation on that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::visit` is your friend here. Convert `types` to a certain `std::variant`/replace it with an alias to that type:

```
// or std::type_identity
template<typename T> struct proxy { using type = T };
template<typename T> constexpr inline proxy<T> proxy_v{};
using var_types = std::variant<proxy<foo>, proxy<bar>>;
var_types mk_var_types(types t) {
    switch(t) {
        case types::foo: return proxy_v<foo>;
        case types::bar: return proxy_v<bar>;
    }
}
```

/write a custom `std::visit`-like for `types` (all three choices are equivalent, but replacing `types` is the shortest)

```
template<typename F>
decltype(auto) visit(F &&f, types t) {
   switch(t) {
       case types::foo: return std::forward<F>(f)(proxy_v<foo>);
       case types::bar: return std::forward<F>(f)(proxy_v<bar>);
   }
}
```

This can be used to implement a `std::variant`-of-`qux`s-returning `create_object`

```
auto create_object(var_types t) {
    std::visit([](auto p) -> std::variant<qux<foo>, qux<bar>> { return qux<typename decltype(p)::type>{} };, t);
}
// or
auto create_object(types t) {
    return create_object(mk_var_types(t));
}
// or
auto create_object(types t) {
     return visit([](auto p) -> std::variant<qux<foo>, qux<bar>> { return qux<typename decltype(p)::type>{}; }, t);
}
```

Which can be used to call `baz`

```
types t;
// or
var_types t;
std::visit([](auto &&q) { baz(std::forward<decltype(q)>(q)); }, create_object(t));
```

Of course, `create_object` isn't necessary in this case

```
visit([](auto p) { baz(qux<typename decltype(p)::type>{}); }, /*mk_var_types(*/t/*)*/);
```

Repeating `foo` and `bar` everywhere is itself a pain. This can be rectified:

```
template<template<typename> typename F>
using variant_with = std::variant<F<foo>, F<bar>>;
using var_types = variant_with<proxy>;
using a_qux = variant_with<qux>;
a_qux create_object(a_type); // etc.
```